# How to check for correct type when calling ObjectWrap::Unwrap in a Nodejs add-on?

Tags: node.js, add-on

I have 2 C++ classes exposed as javascript classes, `VanillaOption` and `NoomraEngine`, both inheriting from `ObjectWrap`.

In the following method in `NoomraEngine`, I m supposed to receive a previously "wrapped" `VanillaOption`:

```
Handle<Value> 
NoomraEngine::Price(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Local<Object> object = args[0]->ToObject(); //  VanillaOption expected in args[0] 

    VanillaOption* equityOption = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<VanillaOption>(object);

    Local<Number> x = Number::New(this->price(equityOption));
    return scope.Close(x);
}
```

Everything works fine except that if I pass the wrong type to the method, node crashes in `ObjectWrap::Unwrap`.

My question is how can I make sure that I've received the correct type in `args[0]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: a better method than the bare V8 one below is to use `NanHasInstance` (https://github.com/rvagg/nan#api_nan_has_instance)

In `MyObject::Init`:

```
Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = NanNew<FunctionTemplate>(New);
tpl->SetClassName(NanNew<String>("MyObject"));
...
NanAssignPersistent(prototype, tpl);
```

where `prototype` is a static `Persistent<FunctionTemplate>` member of `MyObject`.

Use like this:

```
if (NanHasInstance(prototype, handle)) {
    MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(handle);
    ...
}
```

---

With the caveat that this is my first go at writing a Node addon, I solved this exact problem by checking the prototype of the object with my own wrapper around `UnWrap`.

Here's a patch to the addon factory class demo showing the method:
https://github.com/petli/node-addon-examples/commit/d3e92cd060a26da2623690718e78f9005db060a8

It will only support factory-generated objects, and not ones where a constructor is exposed so that users could inherit from the base class.  However, that could be generalised by walking the prototype chain.

In summary, it grabs hold of the reference to the expected class prototype in `MyObject::Init`:

```
Local<Object> obj = constructor->NewInstance();
prototype = Persistent<Value>::New(obj->GetPrototype());
```

And then checks that before dereferencing the object:

```
MyObject* MyObject::CheckedUnWrap(Handle<Object> handle)
{
  if (!handle.IsEmpty() && handle->InternalFieldCount() == 1) {
    Handle<Value> objproto = handle->GetPrototype();
    if (objproto == prototype) {
      // OK, this is us
      return ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(handle);
    }
  }

  ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("<this> is not a MyObject")));
  return NULL;
}
```

All functions then use `CheckedUnWrap` instead:

```
Handle<Value> MyObject::PlusOne(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  MyObject* obj = CheckedUnWrap(args.This());
  if (obj) {
    obj->counter_ += 1;
    return scope.Close(Number::New(obj->counter_));
  }
  else {
    // Invalid type, an exception has been thrown so return an empty value
    return Handle<Value>();
  }
}
```

I was also considering adding an internal field and set that to some some magic pointer, but then the code would have depended on that `node::ObjectWrap` wouldn't change how it uses the internal fields.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I am revisiting this problem and it turns out your answer is "better" than the previously accepted answer. So accepting yours

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Since `NanHasInstance` has been deprecated, the new solution to this answer is to use `bool FunctionTemplate::HasInstance(Local<Value> object)`. This function returns true if the given object is an instance of this function template.

```
Persistent<Function> Wrapper::constructor;
Persistent<FunctionTemplate> Wrapper::tpl;
```

Then in your `Wrapper::Init()` function, set the public Persistent object:

```
Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, New);
// ...
Wrapper::tpl.Reset(isolate, tpl);
```

Now to unwrap:

```
Local<FunctionTemplate> wrapper_tpl = Wrapper::tpl.Get(isolate);
if (!(wrapper_tpl->HasInstance(args[0]))) {
  isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
      String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Argument must be a Wrapper object")));
  return;
}
// Now we are safe to call ObjectWrap::Unwrap
```

Answer (score -1):

node::Buffer::HasInstance(args[0]);

Also see:
http://www.lamedoc.com/node.js/classnode_1_1Buffer.html#a4cc6fa734527df461641c6e93e6d1197