# Get prototype from a constructor without creating an instance in v8

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I am writing a v8 node extension that exports object constructors, as shown in [this documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects). Some of the functions take instances of other classes as arguments, so I want to check the types of those arguments, similar to what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555690/159388) suggests. One thing it suggests is comparing the object's prototype with a known-correct prototype from a temporary instance, like

> ```
> Local<Object> obj = constructor->NewInstance();
> prototype = Persistent<Value>::New(obj->GetPrototype());
> if (instance->GetPrototype() == prototype) { //...
> ```

However, some of my constructors are complex and take instances of the other classes as arguments, so this would be very inconvenient.

My class initialization functions look like this (taken from the linked template):

```
void MyObject::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  // Prepare constructor template
  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
  tpl->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("MyObject"));
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  // Prototype
  tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(String::NewSymbol("plusOne"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(PlusOne)->GetFunction());
  constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(tpl->GetFunction());
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("MyObject"), constructor);
}
```

Is it possible to get a `prototype` object from either the `FunctionTemplate` or the `constructor` such that if I get a new instance `obj` of `MyObject`, `obj->GetPrototype()` will compare equal with `prototype`?

I tried using `tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->NewInstance()` and `constructor->GetPrototype()`, but neither seemed to have the correct value.

---

This is a complete example of what I want to do:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

class MyObject : public node::ObjectWrap {
 public:
  static void Init(Handle<Object> exports);
  static Persistent<Value> prototype;

 private:
  static Handle<Value> New(const v8::Arguments& args);
  static Handle<Value> TypeTest(const v8::Arguments& args);
  static Persistent<Function> constructor;
};

Persistent<Function> MyObject::constructor;
Persistent<Value> MyObject::prototype;

void MyObject::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(New);
  tpl->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("MyObject"));
  tpl->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(
      String::NewSymbol("typeTest"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(TypeTest)->GetFunction());
  constructor = Persistent<Function>::New(tpl->GetFunction());
  prototype = Persistent<Value>::New(tpl->PrototypeTemplate()->NewInstance());
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("MyObject"),
               constructor);
}

Handle<Value> MyObject::New(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  if (args.IsConstructCall()) {
    MyObject *obj = new MyObject();
    obj->Wrap(args.This());
    return args.This();
  } else {
    return scope.Close(constructor->NewInstance());
  }
}

Handle<Value> MyObject::TypeTest(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  if(args.This()->GetPrototype() != prototype) {
    return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::New("This should not happen")));
  }
  return Undefined();
}

NODE_MODULE(hello, MyObject::Init);
```

Currently, if I run the following code in node (after building the addon), I get the type error:

```js
var hello = require('./build/Release/hello');
var obj = new hello.MyObject();
obj.typeTest();
```

Is there any way to set `MyObject::prototype` so that I don't get the error without constructing a temporary instance of `MyObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you set the static prototype value the first time you create an object, rather than inside `Init`? Something like this:

```
class MyObject : public node::ObjectWrap {
   // ... as before ...
};

Persistent<Function> MyObject::constructor;
Persistent<Value> MyObject::prototype;

void MyObject::Init(Handle<Object> exports)
   // ... as before but without setting prototype ...
}

Handle<Value> MyObject::New(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  if (args.IsConstructCall()) {
    MyObject *obj = new MyObject();
    obj->Wrap(args.This());
    prototype = Persistent<Value>::New(args.This()->GetPrototype());
    return args.This();
  } else {
    return scope.Close(constructor->NewInstance());
  }
}

Handle<Value> MyObject::TypeTest(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  if(args.This()->GetPrototype() != prototype) {
    return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::New("This should not happen")));
  }
  return Undefined();
}

NODE_MODULE(hello, MyObject::Init);
```

Comment: Well, I feel a little dumb now. This appears to do exactly what I want. One minor edit: the new line should be `prototype = Persistent<Value>::New(args.This()->GetPrototype()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit. I've incorporated it now. However, for small things like that it's often worth just going in and fixing the code yourself.

Comment: I am generally in the camp that editing code in other people's posts is bad form.